# Implode scripts

Tags: php, arrays, implode

I have an array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => jQuery-2.1.4.min.js
    [1] => bootstrap.min.js
    [2] => menu.js
)
```

How can I implode this to get result:

```
<script src="jQuery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="menu.js"></script>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Maybe...`foreach($scripts as $script) { echo '<script src="' . $script . '"></script>';}`

Comment: Yes. But have no any success using implode function...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

could you try `array_map`

```
$array = array("jQuery-2.1.4.min.js","bootstrap.min.js" , "menu.js");

$filter = function($tag){ return '<script src="' . $tag . '"></script>'; };
$spannedTags = array_map($filter, $array);
echo implode("\n",$spannedTags);
```

Answer (score 1):

Many ways you can do this.

Simple foreach loop:

```
$template = '<script src="%s"></script>';
foreach ($scripts as $script) {
    echo sprintf($template, $script) . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Another, use `array_walk()`:

```
array_walk($scripts, function($script) use ($template) {
    echo sprintf($template, $script) . PHP_EOL;
});
```

[Example](https://eval.in/537026)